# using Rollback in Mysql with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I have a C# application that interact with MYSQL database on server.
I'm using it to insert bills values, in each button press it insert just one value that got from a single textbox.

Is it important to use MySQL Transaction (commit,Rollback) in my case ?! 
i think no, because it just insert one value !?

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your transaction consists of a single insert, then no, you do not require a transaction wrapping the statement, as each statement is intrinsically atomic (and will be [auto-committed by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)).

A single-phase transaction (`START TRANSACTION` ... `COMMIT TRANSACTION`) is required only when you wish to wrap multiple statements in an atomic unit of work.